# How can I force login with the Yammer OAuth API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, yammer

Is there a parameter I can pass to https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth that will force the user to login again?

The problem is if the user is logged into Yammer, it will redirect back to my site, even if the user wants to use a different Yammer account

Twitter's OAuth API accepts a "force_redirect=true" parameter which does what I want, but I can't find one for Yammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such parameter today. The user would have to sign out of Yammer, and this option is in the middle of the authorization dialog:

[image]